# Conflicting Pythons on Mac and in Sublime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, installation, sublimetext3

I'm relatively inexperienced with Python and seem to have gotten confused along the way with trying to upgrade from Python 2.7 to 3.7 on my MacBook Pro with OS 10.10.5 (14F27). I was reluctant to upgrade for a while because I had heard there were some issues but it seems that Python3 is the way to go.

I installed python 3.7.2 for OS 10.9 and was able to get Sublime to use Python3, but when I am in the terminal and try to run python, it looks to the 2.7 bin. Aster I installed some libraries using pip that apparently installed in the 2.7 bin I believe.

At this point I'm very confused and any literature I've read (which I've read quite a bit) generally leads me into a rabbit hole with other things that are wrong, or not up to date, or that I should have but don't.

At this point, is there any way I can just get rid of my Python altogether and reinstall fresh 3.7.2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get rid of the default python 2 on Mac because it is required for some internals. Type `python3` in the terminal to use `Python 3`. Use `pip3` to use `pip` with `python3`.

type `which python3` to see the path of your install.